# I wish to generate multiple images randomly sprinkled on a region in a web browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the first time I am trying some non-trivial dom manipulation in javascript. I am basically partitioning my screen into two halves and randomly inserting five img elements in the left partition.

Here is my code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Faces on the left</title>

    <style>
        img {
            position: absolute;
        }

        div {
            position: absolute;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
        }

        #rightSide {
            left: 500px;
            border-left: 1px solid black;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body onload="generateFaces()">

    <h2>Matching game</h2>
    <p>Click on the extra smiling face on the left</p>

    <div id="leftSide"></div>

    <div id="rightSide"></div>

    <script>
        function generateFaces() {

            var numberOfFaces = 5;
            var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");

            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
                var img = document.createElement("img");
                img.src = "../smile.png";
                var topLoc = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
                var botLoc = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
                img.style.top = topLoc;
                img.style.bottom = botLoc;
                theLeftSide.appendChild(img);
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The picture i wish to generate is :-

[image: Expected output]

The picture i get when i load the page is :-

[image: Observed output]

Its as if the loop does not matter. No matter what value of numberOfFaces I put, the observed img is exactly one face. I debugged the thing, no console errors in Javascript in webstorm and the loop executes 5 times. Is this some weird scoping error in javascript, please help. Its something very silly but I cant pinpoint it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close.  You just need a couple of changes.  First, you need to use units for css positions.  In this case, you should use `px`.  Also, you should set `top` and `left` instead of `top` and `bottom`.  See below.

```js
function generateFaces() {

  var numberOfFaces = 5;
  var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");

  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "../smile.png";
    var topLoc = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
    var botLoc = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
    
    // changes are here!
    img.style.top = topLoc + "px";  // added px
    img.style.left = botLoc + "px"; // and used "left" instead of "bottom"
    theLeftSide.appendChild(img);
  }
}
generateFaces();
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

#rightSide {
  left: 500px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
    <h2>Matching game</h2>
    <p>Click on the extra smiling face on the left</p>

    <div id="leftSide"></div>

    <div id="rightSide"></div>

    <script>

    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. I knew it was something trivial but subtle like "px".